# What does it mean when a piece of clothing cinches you in?

Tags: meaning, verbs, vocabulary, sentence

I've recently heard a girl saying:

### *"the shape (of a dress) cinches you in."*

So the next day, I tried to look up the meaning of it but I've only found the word  *a cinch* which is supposed to be a strap that holds a saddle on a horse.

The dress was tight around the waist area so I thought it can either mean that the dress is tight enough to hold everything (you know what I mean) in place or it makes you look slimmer.

I'm still not quite sure about what she meant so I'd appreciate your answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/cinch_2)

> *cinch something* (especially North American English) to fasten something tightly around your waist; to be fastened around somebody’s waist

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinch)

> verb:  to fasten (something, such as a belt or strap) tightly around someone or something

---

So she was saying that the piece of clothing is tightened around your waist.